# How to delete using sparql

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I fear this is simple question . . . could someone tell me what the sparql is to delete all of a particular type of resource? Not just an individual triple but an entire set of resources.

thank you

Comment: Answer is usually in the specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteWhere

Comment: You can't delete resources in RDF/SPARQL, you can only delete _triples_. Can you elaborate what exactly you want to achieve - are you aiming to delete all type-triples for a particular class, or triples that have a particular resource as their subject, or something else? If possible add some sample (pseudo-)RDF data to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to delete all triples of resources having some class. Try this

`delete {?s ?p ?o}
where {?s a :ClassToDelete; ?p ?o}`